# osTicket 1.9 LDAP pear issue

Tags: ldap, pear, osticket

I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/osTicket/core-plugins to install the LDAP plugin for osticket 1.9.2.

I have the download in the correct place however when I run the command:

```
php make.php hydrate
```

I get loads of 'could not load...' messages and the main fatal one being:

```
Problem 1
- The requested package pear-pear/net_ldap2 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Enabling the plugin within osTicket then works but obvious throws PHP Fatal errors about not finding the ldap files, as you would expect.

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the pear package net_ldap2, either via pear or via composer.